# Sending a mail with cc (multiple email id's) contains link, how to identify specific user clicked on it?

Tags: python, php, email, jwt, sendgrid

I am sending a mail(Gmail) to a group of people in cc and one user is in **to** using PHP which contains a button to acknowledge, I am sending a token with it(I can also use JWT token).
How to know that the acknowledge button is clicked by **to** emailId user, as the token or other things will be same for everyone.

Here is the sample code I am using:-

For sending mail I am using **SendGrid API service in PHP**

```
$tokenValue = 'AnyRandomValueorJWTTokenGoesHere';
$mailContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <a href="localhost:3000/mailVerify.php?myToken='.$tokenValue.'" 
    class="button" > Verify </a>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>';
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("test@example.com", "Example User");
foreach ($cc as $email) {
    $email->addCc($email, explode("@",$email)[0]);
}
$email->addContent("text/html", $mailContent);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

Any help in this regards would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have the user log in to your app first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added sample code to better understand the problem.

Comment: @suchislife I don't want users to log in and then verify.

Comment: Oh, OK. So you wanna connect users to emails without having anything in common. Or worst. They all have the same token but you wanna differentiate them somehow. Good luck that.

Comment: For now, I am sending two mail's one to group of people(cc) and another mail after that just to the person(to address) with unique JWT.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably wanting to use is [Personalizations](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalization). Here's an example of your code using them.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
$dotenv->required(['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);

use SendGrid\Mail\From;
use SendGrid\Mail\HtmlContent;
use SendGrid\Mail\Mail;
use SendGrid\Mail\Subject;
use SendGrid\Mail\To;

$from = new From("sender@example.org", "Example User");
$tos = [
    new To(
        "user1@example.org",
        "Example User1",
        [
            '-name-' => ' Example User1',
            '%token-url%' => 'localhost:3000/mailVerify.php?myToken=54321',
        ],
        "Subject 1"
    ),
    new To(
        "user2@example.org",
        "Example User2",
        [
            '-name-' => ' Example User2',
            '%token-url%' => 'localhost:3000/mailVerify.php?myToken=12345',
        ],
        "Subject 2"
    ),
];
$subject = new Subject("Hi -name-!");
$htmlBody = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <a href="%token-url%" class="button">Verify</a>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
EOF;

$htmlContent = new HtmlContent($htmlBody);
$email = new Mail(
    $from,
    $tos,
    $subject,
    htmlContent: $htmlContent,
);

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($_SERVER['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
}
```

The example above shows how to send a personalised version of the same email to multiple recipients. While none of the users is added to a CC list, as you mentioned in your question, no user will see an email of any other.

Please let me know if this solves your problem.